# crypto protocols from complexity class

Tags: complexity-classes

Assume $P=PSPACE$. Then would it be possible to design cryptographic protocols based that is easy to compute from $PSPACE$ but hard to invert from something higher up in hierarchy?

A function $f: \{0, 1\}^*→ \{0, 1\}^*$ is one-way if $f$ can be computed by a polynomial time algorithm, but for every randomized algorithm $A$ that runs in time 
polynomial in $n=|x|$, every polynomial $p(n)$, and all sufficiently large $n$

$$Pr[ f( A( f(x) ) ) = f(x) ] < \frac{1}{p(n)}$$

where the probability is over the choice of $x$ from the uniform distribution on ${0, 1}^n$, and the randomness of $A$.

Is replacing polynomial time by $PSPACE$, randomized by some other notion possible in above definition if $P=PSPACE$?

Comment: We know that $P \neq EXPSPACE$, unconditionally, because $P \subseteq PSPACE$ and $PSPACE \subsetneq EXPSPACE$ by the space hierarchy theorem. Therefore I don't think we can meaningfully answer your question.

Comment: Ok I misread wiki there.

Comment: No, the existence of one-way functions (OWFs), those that are easy to compute but hard to invert, is a stronger assumption than P != NP. If a function $f$ is easy to compute then the inversion problem is in NP: For a given output $y$, just give the corresponding input $x$ as a witness and check that $f(x) = y$. Therefore "just" assuming P = NP implies that OWFs do not exist.

Comment: You have been changing the question in response to comments.  From reading the current version (revision 4), I have to doubt that you have thought about your own question carefully.  Please take your time trying to solve your own question.

Comment: Only important change to correct mistaken claim $P=EXPSPACE$ as possible. The changes to Huck's comments were only technical.

Comment: While you may have a potentially interesting _idea_ of a question in your mind, the concrete questions your chose to post are uninteresting.  In the first version (revision 1), it was because of hierarchy theorems; in the current version (revision 4), it is because of Savitch’s theorem.  Therefore, please spend your time to think carefully about your own questions.

Comment: aha how does savitch's theorem affect? So The only class we can define crypto protocols is inside NP?

Comment: I will not tell you what Savitch’s theorem has to do with the current version of the question.  Please consider by yourself.  It may take some time, but solving your own question by yourself is usually much more rewarding than being given an answer.